# Why am i getting render distortion bugs with responsive conditional rendering in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, next.js

I have conditional renders in my DOM that only render when the mobile breakpoint has been met. However my webpage still displays or doesn't display those conditional components when they shouldn't be displayed or the page gets completely distorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [blog](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/combining-server-side-rendering-and-responsive-design-using-react/):

> The server doesn’t recognize the window neither document. This means that the device, in other words, cannot detect obligatory properties (such as the viewport dimensions of the client) - thereby it needs to infer them someway, which means, a pretty limited and non-accurate way to respond.
>
> For instance, imagine we’ve an application that uses matchMedia
> (which, as you probably know, is a Web API that arrives on top of
> thewindow) to render components conditionally based on the viewport
> dimensions. How would you expect the server to render the markup
> without thewindow, and even if it’s hypothetically polyfilled somehow,
> what about the dimensions? How would it respond once the initial
> render contains a responsive component that conditionally affected by
> a breakpoint?
>
> Put it simply - this might cause the server to render our application
> incorrectly, which eventually, leads to partial hydration that patches
> the mismatches (namely potential bugs?).

In other words, since its server-side, it does not have access to the dimensions of your screen. Thus the most robust method is to simply use css media queries to conditionally render components.